# Validating and averaging student grades

Tags: python, mathematics

I have myself a little challenge tonight. I've tried to come up with the shortest code for the problem below (the code is pretty self explanatory, except `determinGrade` there which follows the rule

> A - 90-100%
>     B - 80-89%
>     C - 70-79%
>     D - 60-69%
>     F - Below 60%

The code has to be PEP8 complient and no imports (std included) are allowed. Tell me if you can shorten the code further.

```
isValidScore = lambda n: 0 <= n <= 100
calcAverage = lambda *args: sum(args)/len(args)
determinGrade = lambda s: ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'][max(0, (min(s, 99)/10)-5)]


def getValidScore():
    while True:
        try:
            s = int(raw_input('Input score: '))
            if isValidScore(s):
                return s
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print('Score has to be an integer in the range 0 to 100')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scores = [getValidScore() for _ in range(5)]
    print('The scores are: ' + str(scores))
    print('The average is: ' + str(calcAverage(*scores)))
    print('The grade is: ' + determinGrade(calcAverage(*scores)))
```

Comment: This sounds like a [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) challenge.

Comment: @JanneKarila It's fine to want code to be succinct. Shortening to the point of obfuscation would be off-topic — and that is not the case here.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include revised code after an answer has been posted. Read [this](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c)

Comment: @EngieOP, sry too late.. will remember in `__future__` :/

Answer (score 4):

Although this passes the `pep8` tool as of version 1.5.5,
this is not [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) compliant:

> - Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.
> - Always use a def statement instead of an assignment statement that binds a lambda expression directly to an identifier.

If you convert the lambda expressions to `def` statements, the result will be longer, but better.

Also, these statements are a bit tightly packed for my taste:

> ```
> calcAverage = lambda *args: sum(args)/len(args)
> determinGrade = lambda s: ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'][max(0, (min(s, 99)/10)-5)]
> ```

Would have been better this way, but PEP8 does not require it:

```
calcAverage = lambda *args: sum(args) / len(args)
determinGrade = lambda s: ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'][max(0, (min(s, 99) / 10) - 5)]
```

In this last statement, there are some redundant parentheses, this is equivalent:

```
determinGrade = lambda s: ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A'][max(0, min(s, 99) / 10 - 5)]
```

Instead of the `min` hack for the value of 100, how about this way:

```
determinGrade = lambda s: ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A'][max(0, s / 10 - 5)]
```

Last but not least, beware that in Python 3, `27 / 10` will give you `2.7` instead of `2` as in Python 2. As such, the `determinGrade` will try to use a float as the list index, and your script will break. Adopting Python 3 is probably only a matter of time, so it's good to be prepare for that, and use `//` to ensure that you will get an integer index:

```
determinGrade = lambda s: ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A'][max(0, s // 10 - 5)]
```

#### Suggested implementation

Putting the above suggestions together:

```
def is_valid_score(n):
    return 0 <= n <= 100


def calc_average(*args):
    return sum(args) / len(args)


def determine_grade(s):
    return ['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A'][max(0, s // 10 - 5)]


def get_valid_score():
    while True:
        try:
            s = int(raw_input('Input score: '))
            if is_valid_score(s):
                return s
        except ValueError:
            pass
        print('Score has to be an integer in the range 0 to 100')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scores = [get_valid_score() for _ in range(5)]
    print('The scores are: ' + str(scores))
    print('The average is: ' + str(calc_average(*scores)))
    print('The grade is: ' + determine_grade(calc_average(*scores)))
```

Comment: Point taken on the underscore instead of camelcase naming convention. And the lambda bindings. `['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'A'][int(s / 10) - 5]` does not work mate.. e.g with a score on 1 I will get a D. In regard to python3 vs python2, one should use `from __future__ import division`, then there would be no problem. Thanks for you answer, you had some very good points and I will update my code/question så it conforms to pep8 and python3. Do you want another go at the `determine_grade` function?

Comment: Dang, I overlooked that, badly... Thanks for pointing out, fixed it now.

Comment: instead of `int(x/y)`, i'd prefer `x//y`

Comment: @ch3ka I really had a feeling I forgot something but couldn't remember what. You're absolutely right, I prefer `//` too, updated my answer, thanks for pointing out!